# In what situation can snapshot restore be blocked after SET SINGLE_USER?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore, snapshot

In my tests, I have the following script:

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [TestDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE [TestDB] FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'TestDBSnapshot'
```

In some case that I am not able to understand, I get the following error:

```
Database state cannot be changed while other users are using the database 'TestDB'
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Nonqualified transactions are being rolled back. Estimated rollback completion: 100%.
```

It seems the messages are not in the correct order (.NET issue?), but aside from that, what is the situation when I can get `RESTORE` blocked after `SET SINGLE_USER`? I would expect `SINGLE_USER` to give me exclusive access (and it works most of the time).

After this error, the DB is indeed in `SINGLE_USER` state (but not restored).

Answer (score 3):

When you set the database to single user, it allows a single user into the database.  If there's someone else trying to get into the database, and you don't have a connection to the database someone else could get into the database.

A single script like:

```
use master; 
alter database MyDb set single_user; 
use MyDb
```

...is still a single connection.  Something else would need to log into the SQL Server and into that database.  It could be a user, a job, an admin.

Setting the database into restricted user will block anyone who isn't a member of the `db_owner` fixed server role from connecting to the database.  I'd recommend that, or shutdown the app/web servers while you do the database restore.

Answer (score 2):

`SINGLE_USER` will not give you exclusive access *per se*. It will only allow one connection to the DB, and that could very well be another of your own session. I have seen another scenario where the SQL agent connects to the DB and that takes up the `single_user` connection.

When I want to prevent user connections to a DB that is being restored over (with replace), I use `RESTRICTED_USER`.

A `SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` will immediately disconnect users and only allow access to `sa` or `db_owner`.

Comment: The problem I see is not the `SINGLE_USER` blocking me from `RESTORE`, it is `Database state cannot be changed while other users are using the database`. Wouldn't `RESTRICTED_USER` potentially cause the same problem? How is it different from `SET SINGLE_USER ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` given that current connection is not blocked from asking for `RESTORE` in either case?

Answer (score 0):

Execute this before doing restore (DBNAME replace with real one):

```
DECLARE @execSql VARCHAR(1000) = '';

SELECT @execSql = @execSql + 'kill ' +
CONVERT(CHAR(10), spid) + ' '
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE DB_NAME(dbid) = 'DBNAME'
AND DBID <> 0
AND spid <> @@spid;

EXEC (@execSql)
```